# Skip null values in ListActivity with SQLite data 

Tags: android, sqlite, listactivity

I can show the id, title and borrowed values in a `TextView`. My problem is that I would like to check the "borrowed" values, and if they are not `null`, display a simple image. If the value is `null`, I don't want to display anything.

Might work with a `ViewBinder`, but I don't know how to solve this.

```
private static String[] FROM = { _ID, TITLE, BORROWED };
private static String[] TO = { R.id.id, R.id.title, R.id.borrowed };

private Cursor getMovies() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = movies.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}

private void showTitles(Cursor cursor) {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your SimpleCursorAdapter and check for null of the BORROWED val in your overrided bindView() method.  Something like this:

```
private class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{ 

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
             if ( cursor.isNull( cursor.getColumnIndex(BORROWED) ) ){
                   // Handle NULL scenario
             } else {
                   // Handle not NULL scenario
             }
    }
}
```

This is not tested and there's other code you'll need to implement, but this is the idea.

Comment: Looks good but I still don't know what I'm going to do in the "// Handle not NULL scenario" Should I keep the R.id.borrowed in the TO string? I don't want to show that value, I want to show a button or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply where clause in db.query for non null values so that your cursor only has not null rows..

Comment: But I want to display all the id and titles, only not null for the borrowed values. I don't know how to formulate that in query.

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, BORROWED +" IS NOT NULL", null, null, null, ORDER_BY);

Comment: That only shows the titles who's borrowed value is not null :-/ I want to show ALL the titles and have an image on the ones with borrowed value != null

Comment: As your adapter need logic to alter view, you need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter and do whatever you want in bindView method of extended class