# Changing Image for Each Row in Relative Layout - SQLite and Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, layout, adapter, android-relativelayout

I am currently using the following adapter to read from an `SQLite` Database :

```
private static int[] TO = {R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.address, };
private void showPlaces(Cursor cursor) {

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I then also have the following layout file which is referenced from the adapter:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="70dip"
     android:background="@drawable/white"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="10sp">

     <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/Logo"
          android:layout_width="50dip"
          android:layout_height="50dip"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
          android:src="@drawable/picture1" />    

     <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FF000000"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:typeface="sans"  
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/description"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:layout_below="@id/name"
          android:textColor="#0000CC"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/address"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:layout_below="@id/description"
          android:textColor="#990000"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently this code is displaying a `static` image called *picture1*. In my `database` there is a field called Unique `ID` which runs from *1-60*.

What I want to do is somehow display the image to match the Unique `ID` - for example if the Unique `ID` is 2 I want to display the image *picture2*.

Can anyone suggest any way I can do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272899/android-sqlite-listactivity-skip-null-values/7272964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override CursorAdapter.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
... and so on for other TextView's
switch (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("unique_id")) {
case 0:
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);
break;
case 1:
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
break;
... and so on for other images
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Sorry to be really dim, but where does this code go ?

Comment: Create a new class, let's say MyCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter, paste that code there and in your activity change SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO); setListAdapter(adapter); to MyCustomCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCustomCursorAdapter(this,cursor, true); setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Thanks - I get an error message in MyCustomCursorAdapter saying "Implicit super constructor CursorAdapter() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Comment: Then add a constructor to the MyCustomCursorAdapter class

Comment: Thanks. Still have a problem which is that it is crashing. From the logs it looks like the cause is the cursor trying to request column -1 which doesn't exist. Can't spot why this is happening.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read the column that is not in your select statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3172/discussion-between-ohnomycoco-and-nixan)